# How to disable iOS part of FCM unity sdk?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im using the android part of FCM unity SDK for my game, and a standard APNs integrate for iOS platform.

So I want disable the iOS part of FCM unity sdk completely, I removed all the plugins in `iOS` folder, disabled cocoapod settings, but still got this error

```
No GoogleService-Info.plist files found in your project.
```

Comment: When do you get that error?

Comment: @RetiredNinja when i build package on iOS platform.

Comment: If there isn't a simple way to turn off iOS then it's likely their build scripts aren't set up to handle it. I'd look for what's hooked to the pre and post build steps and remove or comment out all of the iOS code that's adding things to the xcode project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just follow the SDK guide download a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from firebase console, mute the build error.

I think this is the only way to disable the iOS part currently.